# Topology types in families of real or complex varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, polynomials, real-algebraic-geometry, stratifications

In René Thom, "Structural Stability and Morphogenesis" on p. 21ff there is the following statement: Let

$$P_j(x_i,s_k) = 0$$

be a set of polynomial equations over the real or complex numbers, where the $x_i$ are coordinates in $X = \mathbf{A}^n_F$ and the $s_k$ coordinates in $S = \mathbf{A}^m_F$ ($F = \mathbb{R}$ or $F = \mathbb{C}$).

If one defines $E_s$ for a certain choice of $s=(s_k^0) \in S$ as the common zeros of $P_j(x_i,s_k^0) = 0$ in $X$ then there is a proper algebraic subset $K \subsetneq S$ (this means $K = V((g_\nu(s_1,\ldots,s_m))_\nu)$ for polynomials $g_\nu$ probably), such that if $s, t$ are in the same connected component of $S - K$, then $E_s$ and $E_t$ are homeomorphic.

In a sense this can be seen as a very strong generalization of the discriminant $\mathrm{disc}_x(P)$ for a single polynomial $P(x,s_k) = x^m + s_1 x^{m-1} + \cdots + s_m$.

*First question*: Has anyone found (and implemented?) an algorithm to compute explicit equations (called $g_\nu$ above) for the set $K$ given a finite number of $P_j(x_i,s_k)$?

*Second question*: Can one generalize to the statement, that there is a finite partition of $S$ into disjoint constructible subsets $S_\alpha \subseteq S$, such that for $s, t \in S_\alpha$ the zero sets $E_s$ and $E_t$ are homeomorphic?

*Third question*: If the second question can be answered affirmatively has anyone found (and implemented?) an algorithm to compute explicit equations for the $S_\alpha$, given the $P_j(x_i,s_k)$.

I tried googling for articles pertaining to the problems above, but found only two that applied specifically to the above question:

https://www.jstor.org/stable/2374240

by Robert M. Hardt, from which I concluded (rightly?), that the second question over the reals can be answered affirmatively.

More on the algorithmic side, I found

https://arxiv.org/abs/0801.1676

from Juan Gerardo Alcazar, where a single $P(x_1,x_2,s_1,s_2) = 0$ is treated with explicit computations.