# Continuous dependence of the (infinite) roots of a polynomial on its coefficients

Tags: polynomials, continuity, hausdorff-measure

I'm trying to show the continuous dependence of the roots of a polynomial on its coefficients when the root number can be infinite (e.g., $x-y$). I don't know much about algebraic geometry but after I asked around, this does not seem so trivial.

Formally, suppose I have polynomials $p_1(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_s), p_2(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_s),\dots,p_k(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_s)$ with real coefficients and fixed degree and number of variables. How do I show continuity ([in this sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemicontinuity#:%7E:text=A%20correspondence%20that%20has%20both%20properties%20is%20said,the%20property%20of%20the%20same%20name%20for%20functions.)) of real zeros with respect to the coefficient? I know it is not true in general, what about locally (coefficients fall within some subsets of $\mathbf{R}^n$ so that multiplicity of real roots do not change) or some modification?

Thanks!

Comment: This is not true even in the single variable case - the set of real roots of $x^2-a$ is not lower hemicontinuous at $a=0$ (if I understand the definitions correctly). That much should be fixed by considering *complex* roots, but upper hemicontinuity can also fail: consider the roots of $ax-1$. In single variable case this can be fixed by imposing that the polynomial be monic, but I have no idea what should be the analogue of that for multivariable polynomials, let alone systems of such.

Comment: Yes that's why I want to restrict only to a connected component, where in finite root cases, multiplicity of the real roots are fixed, i.e., $a\neq 0$ in your first example.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean - connected component of *what* are you taking?

Comment: I might be using the wrong concept (again, not familiar with ag at all). What I would like to know is locally, or within some algebraic constraint set, can I show continuity of the aforementioned sense?

Comment: Maybe the following question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/430893/topology-types-in-families-of-real-or-complex-varieties might give you a start for further thoughts about the problem.

Comment: Perhaps something like: the parameter space belong to some R^k. Then, by removing sets of dimension at most R^(k-1), the roots of the polynomial are continuous on the remaining open set.

Comment: @PerAlexandersson Sounds like something I want!

Comment: @JürgenBöhm Thanks